# Cohomological ($p$-)dimension of a pro-$p$ group

Tags: abstract-algebra, homology-cohomology, group-cohomology, pro-p-groups, profinite-groups

I have a question concerning the cohomological dimension and $p$-dimension of a pro-$p$-group. Let's first recall the definitions of that

The **cohomological dimension** $cd \ G$ of a pro-finite group $G$ is the smallest integer $n$ such that 
$$H^q(G,A) = 0 \text{ for all } q > n$$
and all $G$ torsion modules $A$. Analogously, the **cohomological $p$-dimension** $cd_p \ G$ is the smallest integer $n$ such that 
$$H^q(G,A)(p) = 0 \text{ for all } q > n$$
an all $G$ torsion modules $A$. (Here, $A(p)$ denotes the $p$-primary part for an abelian group $A$).

My question is really simple I guess.

> For a pro-$p$ group $G$, how are $cd \ G$ and $cd_p \ G$ related?

For an arbitrary profinite group $G$, we have 
$$cd \ G = \sup_p cd_p \ G$$
But this does not really help me. My guess is that they're in fact equal. Do you have any hints for me? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $G$ is a pro-$p$ group and we require our cocycles to be continuous, then
$$
H^q(G, A)
$$
will already be $p$-primary for any $G$-torsion module, and so your guess is right. (Proof: cohomology commutes with direct limits, so we may assume $A$ is finite. Decompose $A$ as an abelian group. Any summand of $A$ of order prime to $p$ has trivial continuous cohomology, and the remaining cohomology is killed by any power of $p$ killing the $p$ part of $A$.)

Comment: I have in fact the same question and I do not completely understand your answer. Why does every summand of $A$ of order prime to $p$ have trivial cohomology. Moreover what do you meanby by "the remaining cohomology is killed by any power of $p$ killing the $p$ part of $A$". I hope you can answer my question, this is something I am wondering about for some days now and I could not find any answer... Thank you in advance!

Comment: @Mathoman In this comment answering only your first question: if we take continuous cohomology, then any particular cochain is a cochain for a finite quotient of $G$, but such a thing is automatically a coboundary because: (in general if $G$ and $M$ are finite of coprime order, then $H^i(G, M) = 0$. Standard argument: restriction to the trivial subgroup followed by corestriction back to $G$ is multiplication by the order of $G$; this is on the one hand an automorphism of $M$ and on the other hand the zero map since it factors through $H^q(G, M)$ and so $H^q$ is zero.)

Comment: @Mathoman in this comment answering only your second question. My language was sloppy. I mean, we are trying to show that everything in this module is killed by a power of $p$. But since $A$ itself is finite and since we agreed that the summands of $A$ that aren't $p$-groups contribute nothing, then the power of $p$ that kills the $p$-primary part of $A$ also kills this cohomology group.

Comment: Thank you so much for this quick and very clarifying answer! I finally understood this!!!